# Remove Section of Input - PYTHON

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I am creating a digital to analogue converter. I have a variable storing the user's input, which should be a digital time (e.g 13:00). I then doing inputVariable%12 to get the time as it would be on an analogue clock (e.g 1). However, to do this I need to delete any extra information the user has given (e.g :00) so I only have stored the number. How do I do this?

```
time = input("Enter digital time here:\ne.g 12:00\n")
#Delete extra information here
time = int(time)
time = time%12
time = str(time)
print(time + " o'clock")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that there would be no errors in your input (e.g. user entering some other character, hours above 23, etc.). Considering your input format you should first split on `:`. This should give you two parts: hours and minutes. After this you can process as you want:

```
time = input("Enter digital time here:\ne.g 12:00\n")
hours, minutes = time.split(':')
hours = int(hours)
hours = hours % 12
hours = str(hours)
print(hours + " o'clock")
```